# Deleting QTreeView item using custom context menu crashes

Tags: c++, qt

I have my QTreeView with custom model and items. Each item can have context menu triggered by right click. My problem is that when I am trying to refresh the View after deleting an item using its context menu, the application crashes because it get segmentation fault. The context menu is run in other thread by exec() so it doesn't know when the item (and its context menu QMenu) is deleted and crashes.

```
void ProjectExplorerDock::onCustomContextMenu(const QPoint& point)
{
  QModelIndex index = this->pProjectExplorerView->indexAt(point);
  auto item = static_cast<TreeItem*>(index.internalPointer());
  if(item)
  {
    if(item->getMenu())
    {
      item->getMenu()->exec(this->pProjectExplorerView->viewport()->mapToGlobal(point));
    }
  }
}
```

The triggered action emits a signal to delete the item. I've tried to do this after the exec() like this:

```
void ProjectExplorerDock::onCustomContextMenu(const QPoint& point)
{
  QModelIndex index = this->pProjectExplorerView->indexAt(point);
  auto item = static_cast<TreeItem*>(index.internalPointer());
  if(item)
  {
    if(item->getMenu())
    {
      item->getMenu()->exec(this->pProjectExplorerView->viewport()->mapToGlobal(point));
      emit refreshProject();
    }
  }
}
```

but it's much more work to distinguish if it is necessary to refresh or not.

Is there a way to stop the exec() when the QMenu is deleted?

Example function to show how it is done. It is called every time I want to refresh the view. Each TreeItem has QMenu.

```
void ProjectExplorerDock::fillModel(Project& project)
{
  delete pTreeModel;
  pTreeModel = new TreeModel(mHeaders);
  if(!project.getName().empty())
  {
    QList<QVariant> projectName {QString::fromStdString(project.getName()), ""};
    TreeItem* projectNameItem = new TreeItem(projectName);
pTreeModel->addNewTreeItem(projectNameItem, pTreeModel->getRootItem());
pProjectExplorerView->setModel(pTreeModel);
```

```
void TreeModel::addNewTreeItem(TreeItem* item, TreeItem* parentItem)
{
  beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount(), rowCount());
  item->setParent(parentItem);
  parentItem->appendChild(item);
  endInsertRows();
}
```

Comment: It would be useful if you show the code that deletes tree view items.

Comment: @vahancho just deletes the model with all its items and creates a new one or deletes only one item and creates a new one. This way works when it's not called from the context menu

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the answer.
Before deleting the QMenu make sure to call `QMenu::hide()` to stop the use of it.